# LD can't find libraries in /usr/local/lib or /usr/lib

Tags: c++, macos, ld, clang++, linker-errors

```
clang++ -o $out $in -lbgfxRelease
```

I've built and placed the BGFX library `libbgfxRelease.a` in both `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib`. However, none of them seem to be detected by LD...

```
FAILED: clang++ -o ../bin/test-experimental/test-experimental obj/debug/test-experimental/experimental.o ../bin/attenua/libattenua.a -lbgfxRelease
ld: library not found for -lbgfxRelease
```

until I do

```
clang++ -o $out $in -L/usr/local/lib -lbgfxRelease
```

This is through ninja, but just using clang in terminal has this error. And this is not just bgfx, I tried it with other libraries like SDL2.

I just don't understand...

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you saying using `-L/usr/local/lib` does not work from the command line?  What do you use in place of `$out` and `$in`?

Comment: Out and in are ninja vars. the real values are seen in the error message I showed. The real problem is that I have to specify usr lib and usr local lib as directories; they should be default. Likely a clang error? I have no idea, I used it successfully a few weeks ago and I have no idea why it's not finding the libraries automatically

Comment: `/usr/lib` will be default, but not `/usr/local/`.  That's always been the case as far back as I can remember (late 1980s).

Comment: Hmm. Well it's really too bad I can't get on coding right now to check, but I'm def. sure libraries in usr lib were not found automatically.

Comment: Well, I just checked: `/usr/lib` is not working. However, I noticed that all the libraries there are .dylib except for mine, and I tried one of them, which linked. Is that the problem? Is archive .a not supported?

Comment: No it's supported.  You shouldn't be installing into `/usr/lib` anyway as `/usr/local` is for user files.

Comment: Facing the same issue